# A random sample of size r taken with replacement from a n-sized population such that exactly N given elements will be included in the sample

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

*(Feller Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications - Volume I - 3rd edt.)*

In his book, Feller presents the following formula for obtaining the number of ways for taking a sample of size $r$ without replacement from a population of size $n$ so that $N$ given (already chosen) elements will be in the sample:
$$\binom{n - N}{r - N}.$$

For the *with-replacement* case, otherwise, he claims it can't be derived from a direct argument.

After, in the same chapter, he presents the following formula for obtaining the probability $u(r,n)$ that N given people will be included in the sample with replacement of size $r$ drawn from a population of size $n$ as:
$$u(r,n) = \sum_{v = 0}^N (-1)^v \binom{N}{v} \left(1 - \frac{v}{n} \right)^r.$$

**My question is:**

How can this formula be derived?
Why can't we just solve this problem as the number of natural solutions of:
$$x_1 + ... + x_n = r$$
such that, **WLOG**, ${x_1, ..., x_N} \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ and ${x_{N+1}, ..., x_n} \in \mathbb{N}?$

Hence, the solution would be:
$$\binom{n + r - N - 1}{r - N}.$$

Comment: Presents the formula for *what*?  Please define the terms for people without access to the book.